# one element is going over another element in html and css

Tags: javascript, html, css

help me out with this problem or give me a hint.
here is the problem I am having: I have created a webpage with header element:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <header>
        <a class="header-brand" href="responsive.html">Dark media</a>
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="#">Portfolio</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">About me</a> </li>
                <li> <a href="#">Contact</a> </li>
            </ul>
            <a class="header-cases" href="cases.html">Cases</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
</div>
```

I made it fixed on top of the page so it is always visible when you scroll down the page with this CSS properties:

```
header {
    position: fixed; 
    top: 0;
    right: 0; 
    left:0; 
    background-color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 0 auto; 

}
```

below the header element, I inserted video and it is going over header instead of going down. header element should have been.

```
<video src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ytHTIdpVM2M&list=PL0eyrZgxdwhwNC5ppZo_dYGVjerQY3xYU&index=20" controls>
 </video>
```

here are CSS properties of video:

```
video {
    display: block; 
    width: 80%; 
    padding: 10px; 
    margin: 0 auto; 

}
```

Now video element is going over the header element when scrolling instead of going down. I tried to use z-index but it did not help...I am making a mistake somewhere but cannot find where. Please give me a hint where to find a solution

Comment: it is working perfectly here. I added z-index to the `header` https://jsfiddle.net/zp8j0qk5/

Comment: yes indead it is working in jsfiddle, unfortunately not working properly in my browser, maybe I did not provide some other details from my html and css, thanks for review!!!

Comment: You may add some of your code, especially your CSS style. Or better use the code snippet to reproduce the issue.

Comment: when I first glanced at jsfiddle, did not notice z-index:99, now I did see it, you gave me solution, thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

Apply a `z-index` value to a header styles. It helps to move the header element to upper point along the `z` axis.

```
header {
   position: fixed; 
   z-index: 999;
   top: 0;
   right: 0; 
   left:0; 
   background-color: #fff;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100px;
   margin: 0 auto; 
 }
```

Comment: VSM, used z-index:999; it worked, thanks a lot!!! have a nice day!!!